# Azure graph explorer virtual machines instanceviews vmAgentVersion

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, kql, azure-resource-graph

I'm trying to use azure graph with kusto query to get the agent version of a vm.
With [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machines/instance-view?tabs=HTTP), we can do "/instanceView" to get vmAgent.vmAgentVersion

but with Azure Resource Graph explorer, the instanceView is limited to "PowerState".
I didn't find any way to have that information with kusto. Any suggestions ?

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure Resource Graph explorer, you will get:

```
resources
| project properties,
type
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
```

**Output:**

```
instanceView": {
            "hyperVGeneration": "V1",
            "computerName": "ceuubfcv",
            "powerState": {
                "displayStatus": "VM running",
                "code": "PowerState/running",
                "level": "Info"
            },
            "osVersion": "18.04",
            "osName": "ubuntu"
        }
    },
    "vmId": "76vvgtchiufd4e"
}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use below PowerShell command to get vm version agent and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/invoke-azrestmethod?view=azps-9.1.0) and @Rakhesh sasidharan's [Blog](https://rakhesh.com/azure/azure-finding-vm-agent-version/):

```
$vio = (Invoke-AzRestMethod -Path ('/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{2}/instanceView?api-version=2021-11-01' -f "XX","YY","ZZ") -Method 'GET' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content | ConvertFrom-Json)
$vio
$vio.vmAgent
```

XX-Subscription ID
YY-Resourcegroup
ZZ- Name Of VM

[image]

Using KQL, I found below query you can get agent id and some details of vm:

```
VMComputer
```

So you can use [Rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machines/instance-view?tabs=HTTP) , resource graph and powershell to get details of Vm. Using KQL all the details are not retrieved AFAIK.

Comment: I agreed about powershell rest api, that is what I already do, but it is slower (need to be done vm per vm). My question is to have that information via KQL directly, as I can have powers status for instance. You finish your answer by "VMComputer", what do you mean by that ? Thanks

Comment: [Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/microsoft-azure-kql-query-to-get-the-vm-computer-properties/) about VmComputer, Mostly AFAIK, Using KQL you cannot get the details you are looking for.